# EntityFramework Core SavingChanges into database

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm doing some migration data from one old database to new database.  New database is created with EF Core Code-First using Fluent API.
All tables are migrated successfully expect one. On this table when I want to save some change in database I'm getting error that field "Rejected" is null, even if is not null.
[image: description]
 That field is integer type.

Also I had made some SQL Profiling and I saw that for some reason, this field is missing in Insert Into [image: description]

Any help to understand why this is happen I will appreciate.

**UPDATE:**

```
 public class Entries
    {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreateDateTime { get; set; }

    public int CartonBoxId { get; set; }

    public CartonBoxes CartonBox { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public int Accepted { get; set; }

    public int Rejected { get; set; }

    public DateTime? UpdateDateTime { get; set; }

    public int MasterCodeId { get; set; }

    public MasterCodes MasterCode { get; set; }

    public int SubCodeId { get; set; }

    public SubCodes SubCode { get; set; }

    public int AqlId { get; set; }

    public Aqls Aql { get; set; }

}



public DbSet<Fashions> Fashions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AqlVersions> AqlVersions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Aqls> Aqls { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MasterCodes> MasterCodes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SubCodes> SubCodes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CartonBoxes> CartonBoxes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Entries> Entries { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {

        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasMany(x => x.Entries)
                .WithOne(x => x.User)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId);
        });

        builder.Entity<Fashions>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            entity.Property(x => x.Id)
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            entity.Property(x => x.Name)
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsRequired();

            entity.HasMany(x => x.Aqls)
                .WithOne(x => x.Fashion)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.FashionId);
        });
        builder.Entity<AqlVersions>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(x => x.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            entity.HasKey(x => x.Id);

            entity.Property(x => x.Name)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            entity.HasIndex(x => x.Name).IsUnique();

            entity.HasMany(x => x.Aqls)
                .WithOne(x => x.AqlVer)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.AqlVerId);

        });

        builder.Entity<Aqls>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(x => x.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            entity.HasKey(x => x.Id);

            entity.HasMany(x => x.Entries)
                .WithOne(x => x.Aql)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.AqlId);

        });

        builder.Entity<MasterCodes>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(x => x.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            entity.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            entity.Property(x => x.Code)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50);
            entity.Property(x => x.Eng)
                .HasMaxLength(50);
            entity.Property(x => x.Srb)
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            entity.HasMany(x => x.SubCodes)
                .WithOne(x => x.MasterCodes)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.MasterCodeId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            entity.HasMany(x => x.Entries)
                .WithOne(x => x.MasterCode)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.MasterCodeId);

        });

        builder.Entity<SubCodes>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(x => x.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            entity.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            entity.Property(x => x.Code)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50);
            entity.Property(x => x.Eng)
                .HasMaxLength(50);
            entity.Property(x => x.Srb)
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            entity.HasMany(x => x.Entries)
                .WithOne(x => x.SubCode)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.SubCodeId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        });

        builder.Entity<CartonBoxes>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            entity.Property(x => x.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            entity.Property(x => x.CartonBox)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            entity.Property(x => x.ManuallyStatus)
                .HasMaxLength(20);

            entity.Property(x => x.Sku)
                .HasMaxLength(20);

            entity.Property(x => x.Po)
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            entity.HasMany(x => x.Entries)
                .WithOne(x => x.CartonBox)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.CartonBoxId);
        });

        builder.Entity<Entries>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            entity.Property(x => x.Id)
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            entity.Property(x => x.Status)
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            entity.Property(x => x.UpdateDateTime)
                .IsRequired(false);

            entity.Property(x => x.Accepted)
                .HasDefaultValue();

            entity.Property(x => x.Rejected)
                .HasDefaultValue();

            entity.Property(x => x.MasterCodeId)
                .HasDefaultValue(null);
            entity.Property(x => x.SubCodeId)
                .HasDefaultValue(null);

        });

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
```

Comment: If the field is not included in the `INSERT`, then you have configuration issue. Show the relevant parts of the entity in question and fluent configuration.

Comment: I had update question with code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `HasDefaultValue`:

```
entity.Property(x => x.Rejected)
                .HasDefaultValue();
```

EF Core won't include in the insert command properties marked with `HasDefaultValue` when the property value is equal to the default value specified (`0` in your case).

I would suggest not using `HasDefaultValue` / `HasDefaultValueSql` at all, except the corresponding column in the database table has a default expression. If you don't want similar surprises, remove it from other properties fluent configuration as well.

See [Default Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/default-values) section of the documentation.

Comment: I had tried, it is same. I had added that because I want to be written 0 in database if value doesn't exist. But exist, and error is not for 0,error is for NULL.

Comment: If it wasn't clear, you must remove `HasDefaultValue` from `OnModelCreating`. This way EF Core will include `Rejected` property in the insert command even if it has value `0`. You see `NULL` in the exception message because the column is not included in the insert command due to the reason explained in the answer.

Comment: Am not agree with you. If I remove that line, when I do migration EF will take int Rejected, and based on data annotation EF will consider as not null, so based on that I need to enter int? Rejected , with this it will be consider as nullable. But I'm wondering from FluentAPI is possible to set this int property as nullable ?

Comment: Honestly after your comments I don't understand what are you trying to do - sounds like XY problem. At the end, what is the type of the database table column in question - nullable or not?

Comment: As I wrote above. My question is why I'm getting an error that field can not be null even if I have value. Why that value is not recognized ?

Comment: Because as I said several times, value 0 (zero) is not included in the `INSERT` SQL command. I don't know how to say it simpler - with your `HasDefaultValue` you are telling EF Core: don't include `Rejected` in the `INSERT` if it is 0. Set `Rejected` to `1`, `Accepted` to `0` and you'll start getting the same exception for `Accepted` column. The problem IS `HasDefaultValue`. Anyway, all that is in the answer.